Cannot get Semantic-Kernel to work in an Azure Web App using Python
I am trying to get semantic-kernel to work in an Azure web app using Python. I am using VS Code. Every time I 'Deploy to the Web App' where there is a Python scirpt that includes something like the following: from semantic_kernel import Kernel, I get an error message that says ':( Application Error' when I try to access my Azure Web app.
I have confirmed that I have the right packages in my requiremnets.txt file (see below), I have tried to deploy with local dependencies installed, I am using Python 3.10 and that is what the Azure environment is using. Semantic-kernel works just fine locally but not in Azure. If I remove all lines related to semantic-kernel and re-deploy, I can once again access my Azure Web App, without the semantic-kernel functionality of course.
Requirements.txt:
Flask==3.0.3
PyMuPDF==1.24.13
Werkzeug==3.0.6
openai==1.55.0
azure-core==1.31.0
azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.3.3
pytesseract==0.3.13
Pillow==11.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
requests==2.32.3
urllib3==2.2.3
pandas==2.2.3
openpyxl==3.1.5
semantic-kernel==1.12.1
azure-storage-blob==12.24.0
nest-asyncio==1.6.0

The following is my app.py code. The only part of this that is relevant is the pdf_comparison.py code. Everything else was working fine until I added 'import semantic_kernel' into my pdf_comparison.py file (also below).
app.py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from wage_and_apprenticeship import extract_pages
from statement_of_values import sov_main
from payment_summary import payment_summary_main
from address_search import process_file
from pdf_comparison import main_pdf_comparison
import base64
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "./package")

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



#HOME PAGE
@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')



#ADDRESS SEARCH
@app.route('/address_search')
def address_search():
    return render_template('address_search.html')

@app.route('/address_search_upload', methods=['POST'])
def address_search_upload():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    if uploaded_file:
        filename = uploaded_file.filename
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        uploaded_file.save(file_path)

        updated_file_path = process_file(file_path, filename)

        # Read the processed CSV file content
        with open(updated_file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_content = csv_file.read()

        # Send the CSV content to the frontend as JSON
        return jsonify({'filename': os.path.basename(updated_file_path), 'csv_data': csv_content})

    return 'No file uploaded', 400



#STATEMENT OF VALUES
@app.route('/statement_of_values')
def statement_of_values_page():
    return render_template('statement_of_values.html')

@app.route('/sov_upload', methods=['POST'])
def sov_upload():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file part'
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return 'No selected file'
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(file_path)
        image_reply_pairs = sov_main(file_path)
        image_paths = [f'/uploads/{os.path.basename(path)}' for path in image_reply_pairs.keys()]
        csv_data = [reply for reply in image_reply_pairs.values()]
        return jsonify({'image_paths': image_paths, 'csv_data': csv_data})



#WAGE & APPRENTICESHIP
@app.route('/wage_and_apprenticeship')
def wage_and_apprenticeship_page():
    return render_template('wage_and_apprenticeship.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file part'
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return 'No selected file'
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(file_path)
        image_reply_pairs = extract_pages(file_path)
        image_paths = [f'/uploads/{os.path.basename(path)}' for path in image_reply_pairs.keys()]
        csv_data = [reply for reply in image_reply_pairs.values()]
        return jsonify({'image_paths': image_paths, 'csv_data': csv_data})



#PAYMENT SUMMARY
@app.route('/payment_summary')
def payment_summary():
    return render_template('payment_summary.html')

@app.route('/payment_summary_upload', methods=['POST'])
def payment_summary_upload():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file part'
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return 'No selected file'
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(file_path)
        image_reply_pairs = payment_summary_main(file_path)
        image_paths = [f'/uploads/{os.path.basename(path)}' for path in image_reply_pairs.keys()]
        csv_data = [reply for reply in image_reply_pairs.values()]
        return jsonify({'image_paths': image_paths, 'csv_data': csv_data})



#PDF COMPARISON
@app.route('/pdf_comparison')
def pdf_comparison():
    return render_template('pdf_comparison.html')

@app.route('/pdf_comparison_upload', methods=['POST'])
def pdf_comparison_upload():
    prior_year_file = request.files['priorYearPDF']
    current_year_file = request.files['currentYearPDF']

    prior_year_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(prior_year_file.filename))
    current_year_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(current_year_file.filename))
    
    prior_year_file.save(prior_year_path)
    current_year_file.save(current_year_path)

    try:
        annotated_pdf_path = main_pdf_comparison(prior_year_path, current_year_path)

        # Read the processed PDF file content
        with open(annotated_pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            pdf_content = pdf_file.read()

        # Encode the PDF content to Base64
        encoded_pdf = base64.b64encode(pdf_content).decode('utf-8')

        # Send the Base64-encoded PDF content to the frontend as JSON
        return jsonify({'filename': os.path.basename(annotated_pdf_path), 'pdf_data': encoded_pdf})
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": f"Processing failed: {str(e)}"}), 500



#FILE UPLOAD
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

pdf_comparison.py
import fitz 
import asyncio
import ast
import semantic_kernel #THIS IS THE PROBLEM. 
import os

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

def main_pdf_comparison():
    print("Hello World")


Please provide your python script

What does your Azure app service log stream show

Please read [ask] and then edit your question to provide a [mcve]. As written, you haven't provided any code/data/errors - just a requirements.txt

Updated - thanks for the advice everyone. To summarize, the app.py file is calling a function from another file, pdf_comparison.py. Everything works fine until I add import semantic_kernel to pdf_comparison.py.
This is the latest update. The thing that I need help with is semantic_kernel in the pdf_comparison.py file. Everything else is working fine.

The Log Stream shows the following:


Missing Dependency (pandas): Likely due to installation issues during deployment. This does not make any sense though because other files currenlty use pandas and had no problems.


Version Incompatibility (pydantic): Current version (2.9.2) conflicts with semantic-kernel requirements.


Application Initialization Failures: The app crashes during startup, causing the container to fail health checks.


Insufficient Logs for Debugging: Container-level logging is not fully enabled.



I've tried your code and successfully deployed it to Azure Web App without any issues.

. Version Incompatibility (pydantic): Current version (2.9.2) conflicts with semantic-kernel requirements.


The issue you're facing is because the version incompatibility, I got the same error when I used semantic-kernel==1.12.1
As you're using pydantic==2.9.2, you need to use semantic-kernel==1.16.0 for compatibility.
The kernel might work fine on your local computer because the setup is different, but when you deploy it to Azure, it may need some adjustments to run smoothly, especially for tasks that run in the background.
So, I updated semantic-kernel to 1.16.0

My requirements.txt:
Flask==3.0.3
PyMuPDF==1.24.13
Werkzeug==3.0.6
openai==1.55.0
azure-core==1.31.0
azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.3.3
pytesseract==0.3.13
Pillow==11.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
requests==2.32.3
urllib3==2.2.3
pandas==2.2.3
openpyxl==3.1.5
semantic-kernel==1.16.0
azure-storage-blob==12.24.0
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
pydantic==2.9.2

Local output:

After updating the package, I can successfully deploy the application to Azure Web App.

